# Concatenating columns and rows together

Tags: sql, sql-server-express

I have a table with aircraft's and customer options in it.

eg

```
Cust  |  opt1  |  opt2  
------------------------
A     |   abc  |  def   
B     |        |  mno   
F     |        |  pqr   
A     |        |  ghi
```

I use

```
SELECT
Cust,
opt1 + opt2 as options         
FROM myDB where Len(opt1) >1 or Len(opt2) >1
```

Of course I get cust A twice in my result list

```
Cust  |  options  |
------------------------
A     |   abcdef  |    
A     |      ghi  |
B     |      mno  |
F     |      pqr  |
```

How can I condense this query further so that the result becomes:

```
 Cust |  options    |
------------------------
A     |   abcdefghi  |    
B     |      mno     |
F     |      pqr     |
```

Thanks! (Working on SQL server Express)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
SELECT c.Cust, options = ((SELECT c2.opt1 + c2.opt2 
  FROM dbo.myDB AS c2 WHERE c2.Cust = c.Cust 
  FOR XML PATH(N''), TYPE).value(N'./text()[1]', N'nvarchar(max)'))
FROM dbo.myDB AS c
GROUP BY c.Cust;
```

Comment: Thanks, do you have theme heading I can google for on this subject?

Comment: I think I understand what you're asking. "Group concat" or "grouped concatenation" might be what you want to search on?